# Map two Identical models depending on return query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, mapping

I have two tables `ExportCSV` and `ExportCSV2` that are updated every 30 minutes by a procedure. They are identical.

```
public class ExportCSV
{

    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public string LinkedInId { get; set; }
    public string SNUrl { get; set; }
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Organization1 { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public string ExperienceDescr { get; set; }
    ...
```

}

And

```
    public class ExportCSV2
{

    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public string LinkedInId { get; set; }
    public string SNUrl { get; set; }
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Organization1 { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public string ExperienceDescr { get; set; }
    ...
```

}

Depending on which table is updated last I select data in the service layer.

```
 public IQueryable GetExportByClientId(ref string tablename, int ClientId, DateTime? dateFrom, DateTime? dateTo)
    {
        var table = dataContext.GeneralSettings.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "ActiveTableFullExport");
        if (table != null)
        {
            tablename = table.Value;

            if (table.Value.Equals("ExportCSV"))
            {
                if (dateFrom == null || dateTo == null)
                    return dataContext.ExportCSV.Where(x => x.ClientId == ClientId);
                else
                    return dataContext.ExportCSV.Where(x => x.ClientId == ClientId && x.StartDate > dateFrom && x.StartDate < dateTo);
            }
            else
            {
                if (dateFrom == null || dateTo == null)
                    return dataContext.ExportCSV2.Where(x => x.ClientId == ClientId);
                else
                    return dataContext.ExportCSV2.Where(x => x.ClientId == ClientId && x.StartDate > dateFrom && x.StartDate < dateTo);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

The problem arises when the query returns from `ExportCSV2`
In that case, I get an exception

```
System.ArgumentException: 'DbOfTypeExpression requires an expression argument with a polymorphic result type that is compatible with the type argument.'


 public ActionResult GenerateCsvReportByClient(int clientId, DateTime? dateFrom , DateTime? dateTo)
    {

        var query = _fanService.GetExportByClientId(ref tableName ,clientId, dateFrom, dateTo);

        var data = query.OfType<ExportCSV>().ToList();

var fans = data.Select(x => new ExportCSViewModel
            {
                LinkedInId = x.LinkedInId,
                SNUrl = x.SNUrl,
                Fullname = x.Fullname,
                Firstname = x.Firstname,
                Lastname =x.Lastname,
                Organization1 = x.Organization1,
                JobTitle = x.JobTitle,
   }).ToList();
```

How can I map the view model in both cases, not to be depended of the type of the model?

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: 'System.ArgumentException: 'DbOfTypeExpression requires an expression argument with a polymorphic result type that is compatible with the type argument.'
'

Comment: Where in the code do you get it? It looks like `query.OfType<ExportCSV>().ToList();` might be the problem, as this assumes every query returns an `ExportCSV`. Why don't you check `tablename` before deciding the type?

Comment: `var data = query.OfType<ExportCSV>().ToList();`

Comment: Several options: make both classes implement an interface or derive from an abstract class EF doesn't know of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to return a generic IQueryable, in this case, an `IQueryable<ExportCSV>`.

In order to do that, you need to convert your ExportCSV2 collection, to an ExportCSV collection:

```
public IQueryable<ExportCSV> GetExportByClientId(ref string tablename, int ClientId, DateTime? dateFrom, DateTime? dateTo)
    {
        Expression<Func<ExportCSV2, ExportCSV>> selector = x => new ExportCSV() {
            LinkedInId = x.LinkedInId,
            SNUrl = x.SNUrl,
            Fullname = x.Fullname,
            Firstname = x.Firstname,
            Lastname =x.Lastname,
            Organization1 = x.Organization1,
            JobTitle = x.JobTitle,
        }; 


        var table = dataContext.GeneralSettings.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "ActiveTableFullExport");
    if (table != null)
    {
        tablename = table.Value;

        if (table.Value.Equals("ExportCSV"))
        {
            if (dateFrom == null || dateTo == null)
                return dataContext.ExportCSV.Where(x => x.ClientId == ClientId);
            else
                return dataContext.ExportCSV.Where(x => x.ClientId == ClientId && x.StartDate > dateFrom && x.StartDate < dateTo);
        }
        else
        {
            if (dateFrom == null || dateTo == null)
                return dataContext.ExportCSV2.Where(x => x.ClientId == ClientId)
                   .Select(selector);
            else
                return dataContext.ExportCSV2.Where(x => x.ClientId == ClientId && x.StartDate > dateFrom && x.StartDate < dateTo)
                   .Select(selector);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Then you dont need to do this: `var data = query.OfType<ExportCSV>().ToList();` in your controller, just `var data = query.ToList();`

Also, you need to write the selector for all fields. I would use Automapper library for that.

Comment: `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0815 Cannot assign lambda expression to an implicitly-typed variable`

Comment: Sorry, I can't use var into the selector variable, I will update the answer.

Comment: I have 300 fields for mapping... I really should start using automapper :)

Comment: If you start using Automapper you just have to do `return dataContext.ExportCSV2.Where(...).ProjectTo<ExportCSV>()`;

Comment: var data = query.ToList(); `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no accessible extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` Should I return List From service? Instead of Iqueriable?

Comment: I think you are missing a `using` statement in the controller, in order that `IQueryable` can use the ToList method. Can you show the using part of your Controller?

Comment: `using CsvHelper;
using Entities.Enum;
using Fanbase.Models;
using Fanbase.ViewModels.CampaignsViewModels;
using Fanbase.ViewModels.FansViewModels;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Pitch121.Entities.ExportCSV;
using Pitch121.Entities.Fans;
using Pitch121.Entities.LinkedInProfiles;
using Pitch121.Services.Interfaces;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;`

Comment: Personally, I don't like to use IQueryables in controllers. I would return a list or an IEnumerable in the GetExportByClientId method, but that is offtopic of the question

Comment: If this worked for you, please mark the answer as correct and vote for it, please!

Comment: I Had an exception  >>Failed to construct  Entity<<probably due to mistake to mapping. However, a perfectly sound answer, I learned a lot from your answer so I will accept as an answer. I will post how I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem.

```
public ActionResult GenerateCsvReportByClient(int clientId, DateTime? dateFrom , DateTime? dateTo)
    {
        List<ExportCSV> mainList = new List<ExportCSV>();

        var tableName = "";
        IQueryable query = _fanService.GetExportByClientId(out tableName ,clientId, dateFrom, dateTo);

        //var data = query.OfType<ExportCSV>().ToList();

        if(tableName == "ExportCSV")
        {
            var datalist = query.OfType<ExportCSV>().ToList();
            mainList = datalist;
        }
        else
        {
            var datalist = query.OfType<ExportCSV2>().ToList();
            mainList = datalist.Select(x => new ExportCSV{

                LinkedInId = x.LinkedInId,
                SNUrl = x.SNUrl,
                Fullname = x.Fullname,
                Firstname = x.Firstname,
                Lastname = x.Lastname,
                Organization1 = x.Organization1,
                JobTitle = x.JobTitle,
                Email = x.Email,
                ExperienceDescr = x.ExperienceDescr,
                ProfileLocation = x.ProfileLocation,
                OrganizationDescription1 = x.OrganizationDescription1,
                Organization1Industry = x.Organization1Industry,
                ....
                }
}
```

I'll try automaper next time for sure :)